# Thunderbird in Ubuntu 16.04: Calendar view disabled?

Tags: 16.04, thunderbird, lightning

I'm running a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using the version of Thunderbird that came with it, plus updates (version 45.5.1). I've installed Lightning (4.7.4), which works, and I've set up the Google Calendar Provider add-on as well.

The issue is that I can't access the Calendar view and all of the menu options pertaining to calendars throughout Thunderbird are disabled (including Edit > Calendar Properties, View > Calendar, View > Tasks, etc.)

I tried removing Lightning. This just completely removed those menu items from Thunderbird. Reinstalling Lightning didn't help.

Any idea what's up here or how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be running Lightning 4.7.4. It can be downloaded at https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/projects/calendar/

The calendar-related menus only work if the calendar tab is the front tab. Same with the tasks menus, the tasks tab has to be in front.

Comment: Unbelievable - I had no idea it was that simple. Thanks so much!